# Volunteer travel in South East Asia / Africa

Tags: southeast-asia, africa, volunteering

I want to go for a volunteer trip to  south-east Asian countries or Africa. Although I found a website called STAtravel. I am looking for some more pointers for a lesser price. As far as skills are concerned, I am software and electrical engineer and a flute player with English knowledge and I can teach yoga too.

Comment: Some country? could you perhaps be more specific? As per our [faq], this is currently far too broad a question and covers ... well the whole world.  Is there a particular area you're interested in - near Singapore, perhaps, or are you looking further afield?

Comment: @MarkMayo south east asian countries and africa if you want to be more specific..

Comment: It's not whether *I* want it, you're the one with the question, and if you're going to ask them on here, all we do is ask that you follow the guidelines in the [faq] - you're far more likely to get positive and useful answers ;)  Nice re Africa and SE Asia.  Amazing places with a huge demand for volunteers.

Comment: @MarkMayo. Thanks.:) Hope to get positive answers.

Comment: I don't think STATravel is related to a volunteer travel. It seems like a website that sell cheaper flight to student / teacher.

Comment: @dagalti: You'll still need to provide a bit more info.  Are you saying you are willing to pay to be a volunteer? Or do you want to get paid (however little). And how long would you expect to be in any one place? Are you thinking of moving abroad permanently? Are you looking for incidental volunteer work, or do you want to do something more structural? Is your objective to volunteer in a specific place, or do you want to travel around, occasionally putting your skills to use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Travel by working?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10734/travel-by-working)

Comment: @Rudy I think this is not duplicate, because here the region is defined, so someone may found something special for OP.

Comment: Check out this useful tips "7 ways to be a successful volunteer abroad"
[ here are our seven tips for being a great one!](https://www.knowbetween.com/list/7-ways-to-be-a-successful-volunteer-abroad)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Volunteer HQ](http://www.volunteerhq.org/affordable-volunteer-fees.html) is a reputable company.  Their program fees are also cheaper than STA's.

If you're traveling for a few months, Try [VSO](http://www.vsointernational.org/volunteer/current-roles.asp).  They're looking for professionals and will even pay a living allowance and other costs.

Answer (score 3):

[DIVOG](http://www.divog.org/volunteer-abroad/) (Disaster Volunteers of Ghana) seems to have some good volunteer programs in Ghana.

I have not personally travelled with DIVOG, but I found this site through a photographer that took his family on one of the family volunteer programs with them.  A blog entry of photos from his trip is here: http://marksolonfstop.com/2013/01/05/dzolo-gbogame-ghana/

> In the summer of 2010, my family spent a week living in the beautiful and lush tiny village of Dzolo Gbogame, a four-hour drive north of the capital of Accra. We lived in a small home in the village for a week and helped build a washroom facility behind a building which served as the village’s school, church and community center. Despite living conditions that would make most westerners cringe, the folks in Dzolo Gbogame were some of the happiest people we’ve ever met. I’m sure that being part of a tight knit community had a lot to do with that.
>
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> <sup>(Images and text from http://marksolonfstop.com/2013/01/05/dzolo-gbogame-ghana/)</sup>

I don't think his site mentions DIVOG, but in a Facebook post the author of the blog said that  DIVOG was the organization that they worked with for their trip, and that they took great care of them.